# PHP Update MySQL from CSV Skip Row on Error

Tags: php, mysqli, fgetcsv

So basically, I have a CSV file that will be uploaded but not stored on the server and PHP will pull data from it and update a database accordingly.

My Issue is that I am trying to skip the row in the CSV if there is already an entry found in the database but it stops on the first error and does not skip.

Line 62, I added a comment which is where I am trying to get this accomplished.

the ELSE statement after the if (($update == 1) && ($update2 == 1)) has a continue in it, meaning if update and update2 do not == 1 then skip, or so I would have thought but it just stops after the first duplicate serial number is found.

Any help is GREATLY appreciated

```
    public function upload() {
    $this->data['token'] = $this->session->data['token'];
    $connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "username", "password", "database");
    $this->load->model('setting/mail');
    if (isset($_POST["upload"])) {
        if ($_FILES['update_cases']['name']) {
            $filename = explode(".", $_FILES['update_cases']['name']);
            if (end($filename) == "csv") {
                $handle = fopen($_FILES['update_cases']['tmp_name'], "r");
                fgetcsv($handle);
                $this->load->model('sale/order');
                while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
                    print "row start<br>";
                    $order_id = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $data[0]);
                    $product_sn = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $data[1]);
                    $customer_email = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $data[2]);
                    $status = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $data[13]);
                    $rma_number = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $data[17]);
                    $rma_type = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $data[18]);
                    $planned_product = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $data[19]);
                    $tur = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $data[20]);
                    $pi = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $data[21]);
                    $cir = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $data[22]);
                    $cmr = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $data[23]);
                    $waive_return = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $data[24]);
                    $replacement_tracking = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $data[26]);
                    $inventory = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $data[27]);
                    $replacement_sn = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $data[28]);
                    $replacement_sn2 = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $data[29]);
                    $qty_shipped = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $data[33]);
                    $date_shipped = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $data[35]);
                    $result1 = $this->model_sale_order->getOrderById($order_id);
                    $current_status = $result1['order_status'];
                    $rma_num = $result1['order_rma'];
                    $customer_id = $result1['cus_id'];
                    $regpro_id = $result1['regpro_id'];
                    $update = 0;
                    $update2 = 0;
                    $batch_data = array(
                        "order_id" => $order_id, 
                        "rpl_tracking" => $replacement_tracking, 
                        "qty_shipped" => $qty_shipped, 
                        "replacement_sn" => $replacement_sn, 
                        "replacement_sn2" => $replacement_sn2, 
                        "inventory" => $inventory, 
                        "rma_type" => $rma_type, 
                        "pi_num" => $pi, 
                        "tur_num" => $tur, 
                        "cir_num" => $cir, 
                        "cmr_num" => $cmr, 
                        "waive_return" => $waive_return, 
                        "update_status" => $status, 
                        "date_shipped" => $date_shipped, 
                        "pre_status" => $current_status, 
                        "comment" => $planned_product, 
                        "planned_product" => $planned_product
                    );
                    if ($qty_shipped !== 0) {
                        $this->load->model('catalog/product');
                        $this->load->model('catalog/regproduct');
                        // If Two replacement products
                        if ($qty_shipped == 2) {
                            //Check if Serial Number Already Exists (If exists, I want the script to skip this row and move onto the next row in the excel sheet)
                            $check_sn = $this->model_catalog_regproduct->checkSNBelong2($replacement_sn);
                            $check_sn2 = $this->model_catalog_regproduct->checkSNBelong2($replacement_sn2);
                            if ($check_sn) {
                                $update = 0;
                                $this->error['error_replacement_sn'] = "SN " . $replacement_sn . " in use!";
                            } else {
                                $update = 1;
                            }
                            if ($check_sn2) {
                                $update2 = 0;
                                $this->error['error_replacement_sn2'] = "SN " . $replacement_sn2 . " in use!";
                            } else {
                                $update2 = 1;
                            }
                            if (($update == 1) && ($update2 == 1)) {
                                $replacement_product = $this->model_catalog_product->getProductBySN($replacement_sn);
                                $replacement_product2 = $this->model_catalog_product->getProductBySN($replacement_sn2);
                                $defective_product_warranty = $this->model_catalog_regproduct->getRegproductById($customer_id, $regpro_id);
                                $warr_date = $defective_product_warranty['regpro_warr_date'];
                                $replacement_model = $replacement_product['m_type'];
                                $replacement_model2 = $replacement_product2['m_type'];
                                $replacement_family = $replacement_product['f_type'];
                                $replacement_family2 = $replacement_product2['f_type'];
                                $this->model_catalog_regproduct->addRegproductReplacement2($customer_id, $replacement_sn2, $replacement_family2, $replacement_model2, $warr_date);
                                $this->model_catalog_regproduct->addRegproductReplacement($customer_id, $replacement_sn, $replacement_family, $replacement_model, $warr_date);
                                $this->model_sale_order->confirmOrder3($this->user->getId(), $batch_data);
                                if (((int)$current_status) !== ((int)$status)) {
                                    if ((int)$status == 210) {
                                        if ($rma_type != "Standard") {
                                            $template = $this->model_setting_mail->getTemplateByLabel('RMA_PRODUCT_RECEIVED_ADVANCED');
                                        } elseif ($rma_type == "Standard") {
                                            $template = $this->model_setting_mail->getTemplateByLabel('RMA_PRODUCT_RECEIVED_STANDARD');
                                        }
                                    } elseif ((int)$status == 230) {
                                        if ($rma_type != "Standard") {
                                            $template = $this->model_setting_mail->getTemplateByLabel('RMA_REPLACEMENT_PRODUCT_SHIPPED_ADVANCED');
                                        } elseif ($rma_type == "Standard") {
                                            $template = $this->model_setting_mail->getTemplateByLabel('RMA_REPLACEMENT_PRODUCT_SHIPPED_STANDARD');
                                        }
                                    } elseif ((int)$status == 500) {
                                        $template = $this->model_setting_mail->getTemplateByLabel('RMA_CLOSED');
                                    }
                                    if ((int)$template['email_status'] == 1) {
                                        $subject = $template['email_subject'];
                                        $message = $template['email_content'];
                                        // Get Customer Email
                                        $this->load->model('sale/customer');
                                        $order_info = $this->model_sale_customer->getCustomerByEmail($customer_email);
                                        $customer_info = $this->model_sale_customer->getCustomer($order_info['cus_id']);
                                        $email = $customer_info['cus_username'];
                                        $this->load->model('sale/order');
                                        $result_tracking = $this->model_sale_order->getOrderById($order_id);
                                        $replacement_tracking = $result_tracking['order_return_tracking_num'];
                                        $message = str_replace('%FIRSTNAME%', $customer_info['cus_firstname'], $message);
                                        $message = str_replace('%LASTNAME%', $customer_info['cus_lastname'], $message);
                                        $message = str_replace('%RMA%', $rma_num, $message);
                                        $message = str_replace('%TRACKING%', $replacement_tracking, $message);
                                        $mail = new Mail();
                                        $mail->protocol = $this->config->get('mail_protocol');
                                        $mail->hostname = $this->config->get('smtp_host');
                                        $mail->username = $this->config->get('smtp_username');
                                        $mail->password = $this->config->get('smtp_password');
                                        $mail->port = $this->config->get('smtp_port');
                                        $mail->timeout = $this->config->get('smtp_timeout');
                                        $mail->setTo($email);
                                        $mail->setFrom($this->config->get('sender_email'));
                                        $mail->setSender($this->config->get('sender_name'));
                                        $mail->setSubject(html_entity_decode($subject, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'));
                                        $mail->setText(html_entity_decode($message, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'));
                                        try {
                                            $mail->send();
                                        }
                                        catch(Exception $e) {
                                            $this->error['warning'] = $e->getMessage();
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                                $this->session->data['success'] = $this->language->get('text_success');
                                //$this->redirect($this->url->link('report/sale_return', 'token=' . $this->data['token'], 'SSL'));

                            } else {
                                print $update."<br>";
                                print $update2."<br>";
                                print "Errors<br>";
                                continue;
                            }
                            //row start
                            //0
                            //0
                            //Errors
                            //row start
                            //0
                            //0
                            //Errors
                            //row start
                            //row end
                            //row start
                            //row end
                            //row start
                            //row end
                        } else if ($qty_shipped == 1) {
                            // will do something else
                        } else if ($qty_shipped == 0) {
                            // will also do something else
                        }
                    } else if (!isset($qty_shipped)) {
                        // will also do something else
                    }
                    print "row end<br>";
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you put a print() statement before continue; to verify it's being hit, also print $update and $update2?

Comment: @sh4dowb sure, I updated the code to reflect your request as well as the output

Comment: Can you keep continue;

Comment: @sh4dowb okay I did that and tried again but same output, doesn't appear anything changed which means it doesn't seem to be accepting the continue

Comment: Can you please add `print "row start";` in the first line of while loop, and `print "row end";` to the ending of loop?

Comment: Ok now please check if "row start" counts match your CSV row count, and "row end" should be (row count - duplicate SN error count). If so, loop doesn't actually stop, but you're not processing the data

Comment: @sh4dowb okay that has been done and I updated the output in the code. I should note, there are 5 test cases in the database and 5 test cases in the csv file. only 2 of which currently have a $status that is not equal to the $current status which is how I need it to run and both of those cases from the csv file have 2 replacement serial numbers each (2 per row to total 4 serial numbers, all of which are already registered so I need it to show all 4 serial numbers as an error instead of only 2)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179594/discussion-between-sh4dowb-and-marz-89).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to show all errors, you should use an array, and append the error text to that array. Then use foreach loop on client part to display all errors.

If you use a single variable it will always be what you set it to most recently. For multiple data, you should use an array, or append to string like this: `$string .= "appended string";` but for this case I recommend using arrays.

Comment: you nailed in man. Got it showing all duplicate SN's without issue now. Thanks again for your help.